# HTML Views (UserControl) for Knockout.js

Tags: javascript, jquery, wpf, mvvm, knockout.js

In a single page application, how to use Knockout.js effectively to achieve MVVM. Is there a way to create views (Html files) and viewmodels (javascript files) separately? That can be referred in another HTML master file.

I tried iframe, but it allows user to navigate to individual views. Is there any other way?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, I think this is possible. If you create each view as a template in a separate html file and then load and append the appropriate template to the documents body when you instantiate you viewmodel.

in pseudo-code you'd get something like:

```
<!-- your page -->
<div id="bindModelHere">
    <!-- ko template: loadedTemplate -->
    <!-- /ko -->
</div>
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function () {
        var viewModel = new yourViewModel();
        ko.applyBindings(viewModel, document.getElementById('bindModelHere'));
    });
</script>


//your javascript
function yourViewModel (){
    this.loadedTemplate = ko.observable();

    //Load template from server with a get and append to document body
    //when loaded and appended do: loadedTemplate("idForTemplate");
}

<!-- the template/view in a separate file-->
<script type="text/html" id="idForTemplate">
    <!-- your html -->
</script>
```

this way you could load your views/templates using ajax and just load the view you'd need.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. How to link the html file which contains "idForTemplate" in main page?

Comment: [reading this](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.get/) and [reading this](https://api.jquery.com/append/) should get you on your way.